# How to make system music stop when my app loads (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So basically I want to stop the iPod music when my app loads up. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Import `AVFoundation`, and `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `MediaPlayer.framework` to your target.

In your `AppDelegate.m` import `MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h` and add this in the

`application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method:

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] stop];
```

Comment: Is it possible to stop when my app is in background ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use this method to get access to the iPod App player:

```
+ (MPMusicPlayerController *)iPodMusicPlayer;
```

Than you just stop it using the appropriate method.. like this:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *player = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[player stop];
```

You should also add the MediaPlayer framework